# How to stop systemLayoutSizeFittingSize from truncating buttons?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, autolayout

I'm trying to show a simple "dialog" using a popover segue on iPad.  I designed the view controller scene in Interface Builder and when the popover appeared it was way too big -- lots of empty space around the label and two buttons.

So I tried using `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` in `viewWillAppear`.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    CGSize size = [self.view systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];                           
    self.preferredContentSize = size;
}
```

It wrapped the content nicely, except it truncated the buttons.

[image]

How do I make it not truncate the button text?

Comment: How close is the size? Does it still truncate if you increase the width by, say, 1 point?

Comment: I just tried. It stops truncating when I add 16 points to the width.

Comment: That sounds suspiciously like there's some 8-pt margin somewhere that's not being taken into account, but I'm not sure where.

Comment: Yup, the layoutMargins are 8 pts. Weird: if I call `layoutIfNeeded` before `systemLayout`, I don't need to add the 16 to width, it just works. Seems like a bug to me. Thanks.